# How to check if Spark RDD is in memory?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, in-memory

I have an instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[MyClass].
How can I programmatically check if the instance is persist\inmemory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want `RDD.getStorageLevel`. It will return `StorageLevel.None` if empty. However that is only if it is marked for caching or not. If you want the actual status you can use the developer api `sc.getRDDStorageInfo` or `sc.getPersistentRDD`

Comment: Thanks Justin for sc.* functions!

Answer (score 2):

You can call rdd.getStorageLevel.useMemory to check if it is in memory or not as follows:

```
scala> myrdd.getStorageLevel.useMemory
res3: Boolean = false

scala> myrdd.cache()
res4: myrdd.type = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at <console>:29

scala> myrdd.getStorageLevel.useMemory
res5: Boolean = true
```