# Cannot change storage level of RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

The following Spark code:

```
val model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings = ratingsRDD,
                              rank = rank,
                              iterations = numIterations,
                              lambda = lambda,
                              alpha = alpha)  

model.productFeatures.cache()

val modelSubsetRDD = new MatrixFactorizationModel(
  rank = rank,
  userFeatures = model.productFeatures,
  productFeatures = model.productFeatures)
```

raises the exception below:

> Cannot change storage level of an RDD after it was already assigned a
>   level

Same exception is raised with `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY`.

On the other hand, the following code works properly:

```
    val model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings = ratingsRDD,
                              rank = rank,
                              iterations = numIterations,
                              lambda = lambda,
                              alpha = alpha)  
    val modelSubsetRDD = new MatrixFactorizationModel(
      rank = rank,
      userFeatures = model.userFeatures,
      productFeatures = model.productFeatures)

    model.userFeatures.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
    model.productFeatures.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
```

Noticed that this time `userFeatures` and `productFeatures` are set to two different members of model. However, I'm not sure why this works.

Comment: If you are still having problems please update your question. If the answer below resolves your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting some persistence from somewhere else in the code?? Not sure what `ALS.trainImplicit` is doing before returning the model.

Calling `cache()` will store the RDD in MEMORY_ONLY while calling `persist` allows you to change the type of caching. So I'm guessing that this RDD has already been persisted somewhere else and you are attempting to re-persist it with `cache()` which is the problem. However, changing the persistence type with `persist` is perfectly acceptable.

edit:

Try the following code:

```
val model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings = ratingsRDD,
                              rank = rank,
                              iterations = numIterations,
                              lambda = lambda,
                              alpha = alpha)  
if(model.productFeatures.getStorageLevel() == StorageLevel.NONE)
    model.productFeatures.cache()

val modelSubsetRDD = new MatrixFactorizationModel(
  rank = rank,
  userFeatures = model.productFeatures,
  productFeatures = model.productFeatures)
```

This should avoid you trying to cache something that has already been cached (either in memory or disk).

Comment: I get the same exception with persist. Strangely, the last piece of code works.

Comment: does MatrixFactorizationModel do any unpersist? Really hard to help with two classes that are basically black boxes.

Comment: yes, but I'm using the same code in both cases. the only difference is that in one case I'm using productFeatures twice..

Comment: That isn't the only difference. When you call MatrixFactorizationModel with respect to your persist/cache call is also reversed. If my guess is correct, then if you take your second code example and move the persist call higher, you will also get an exception.

Comment: You can check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688145/how-to-check-if-spark-rdd-is-in-memory) and only persist the RDD if it isn't already.